# multiple Drupal undefined index errors

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have been making a drupal theme (started from bootstrap)
and all of a sudden these errors showed up and my css isn't loading anymore, so i just get the html-markup

I realy don't get why, site was working great before.
Unrelated question: is there any chance of using my html/css rather than restyling
everything because drupal isn't using my classes?

> Notice: Undefined index: highlighted in include() (line 126 of C:\Bitnami\drupal-7.34-0\apps\drupal\htdocs\modules\system\page.tpl.php).
>
> Notice: Undefined index: sidebar_first in include() (line 138 of C:\Bitnami\drupal-7.34-0\apps\drupal\htdocs\modules\system\page.tpl.php).
>
> Notice: Undefined index: sidebar_second in include() (line 144 of C:\Bitnami\drupal-7.34-0\apps\drupal\htdocs\modules\system\page.tpl.php).
>
> Notice: Undefined index: webshop in drupal_theme_initialize() (line 100 of C:\Bitnami\drupal-7.34-0\apps\drupal\htdocs\includes\theme.inc).
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in _drupal_theme_initialize() (line 146 of C:\Bitnami\drupal-7.34-0\apps\drupal\htdocs\includes\theme.inc).
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in _theme_load_registry() (line 335 of C:\Bitnami\drupal-7.34-0\apps\drupal\htdocs\includes\theme.inc).
>
> Notice: Undefined index: webshop in theme_get_setting() (line 1439 of C:\Bitnami\drupal-7.34-0\apps\drupal\htdocs\includes\theme.inc).
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in theme_get_setting() (line 1486 of C:\Bitnami\drupal-7.34-0\apps\drupal\htdocs\includes\theme.inc).

Comment: check if you see an installation profile name on status report page. if you do, something is wrong with your drupal installation

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you had a theme called 'webshop'. If you can get to yoursite.com/admin/appearance is your theme even visible there? I have seen the same symptoms when my installation profile failed during installation, leaving me with an unfinished install.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to relocate the modules and themes you moved. Then uninstall them and then move them again, where after you should be able to install them again, without getting that kind of errors.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you use a base theme. Add the regions to your own theme, and the errors will disappear :)